# Facebook Conversion shows in conversion tracking page but not in Campaigns page

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-ads-api

I could see the facebook ads conversions in the conversion tracking page but, no conversion is reported in the campaign page or reports.

Any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

How many conversions do you see in the conversion tracking page? It could be that any of the conversions you see has been generated by an Ad, in that case you won't see any conversions attributed to your Ads.

Also, in the report section, be sure to include the needed columns in the report: you can edit the columns and add all data you need.